# Spring wire inherited property

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm using spring jdbctemplate and my DAO `extends JdbcDaoSupport` so I have a common property for jdbcTemplate.

My problem is that I want to wire the property `jdbcTemplate` of `JdbcDaoSupport` using annotation so I don't have to repeat the declaration of bean and wiring of `jdbctemplate` in xml configuration.

Currently I can only wire this through springconfig.xml.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="basicDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="org.jrue.poc.springjdbc.dao.UserDao">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>
```

Is it possible to wire jdbcTemplate property inside my UserDao class ?

Comment: Can you be more clear with youyr Q?

Comment: Please see my explicit question above